# Does a TLS client needs to have intermediate CA in the trust store?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

When a TLS handshake takes place, the server sends in his ServerHello message, his digital certificate. This digital certificate is digitally signed by a intermediate CA named A and CA A also has a certificate which is signed by CA named root whose certificate is self signed, thus forming a certificate chain. The client then has to establish a trust, validating the server certificate. To perform that validation the client has to validate the entire chain correct?
Must the client have in a truststore all the certificates (A and Root) or the client will download them?

Comment: No. The client only needs *any* of the signing certificxtes in the chain in its truststore, usually the topmost. The client has to validate the entire chain as far as the one which it already trusts.

Comment: (1) The server is supposed to send the full chain, up to but optionally excluding the root or anchor; see the RFCs. It does this in a Certificate message, not the ServerHello message. (2) If the server fails to send the chain, the client _may_ have a cache, plus nowadays _many_ CAs include the AuthorityInfoAccess extension and the client _may_ use that to fetch the missing nonroot(s), but it varies depending on the client. The root or anchor must be preinstalled and NOT downloaded, because that download could be tampered or faked.

Comment: Please note that this kind of questions is better asked at [security.se].

Answer (score 18):

The client usually has only the root CA in the local trust store. The leaf certificate and the intermediate certificate leading to the root CA need to be provided by the server. The intermediate certificates are usually send in addition to the leaf certificate within the TLS handshake.

But it is a typical misconfiguration to only have the leaf certificate send by the server. In this case the certificate validation will fail unless the client has already knowledge of the intermediate certificates or can obtain these somehow. Since often the same intermediate certificates are used, some browsers like Firefox will cache the intermediate certificates they'll got when communicating with server A and fill these in when a broken server B is not sending the required intermediate certificates. Other browsers (like Google Chrome) will try to download the missing intermediate certificates from the internet. Most simpler clients (i.e. apps written in Python, Java ... or curl) will instead just fail with a certificate validation error.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is why intermediate certificate should be include? 
Why the client could not juts fetch it using the AIA info, then check its validity against the local custom root CA (that is already in the truststore)?

Comment: @Teenage: AIA is optional. Dynamic lookups of the missing certificate also require connectivity not only to the actual target server - which can not be assumed as possible in all environments. Dynamic lookups also add complexity. And they add latency. That said: Chrome actually uses AIA if the intermediates are not provided.