Certificate chain does not include all certificates sent by server in checkServerTrusted
I've written a Java service that accepts a hostname/port (protocol agnostic) and responds with the entire certificate chain details, including the acceptable CA names provided by the server. After the application connects and extracts SSL certificate data, it immediately disconnects from the host. I've written a custom TrustManager and KeyManager to extract these details.
The SSL socket is initialized like so:
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] { customKeyManager }, new TrustManager[] { customTrustManager }, null);
socket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port, timeout);
socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();

In most cases, it works flawlessly and is able to extract all the relevant details... but I've noticed that with some hosts (in this case, HTTPS connections), it fails to pull the entire certificate chain and client aliases. I validated against openssl CLI and turned on SSL handshake debugging (-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake), and was able to confirm that the server was sending the entire certificate chain.
When checkServerTrusted(...) is invoked, I'm only seeing one certificate. There should be two additional signers (an intermediate and root signer) but they are not present in the chain.
Additionally, in my KeyManager, the chooseClientAlias(...) is never invoked and thus, I am unable to see client aliases.
I omitted the KeyManager and TrustManager implementation but can update this post if needed.

Can you try using a different TrustManager? Can you use a custom one which extends the following trustmanager: https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html And create a sslcontext with this trustmanager.

@Hakan54 No joy... Still only seeing one certificate.

The root certificate is not normally sent, and the intermediate normally is. But those are server configuration details. And, unless the server requests client authentication, chooseClientAlias won't be invoked. The server configuration details are critical to this question.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk It would make sense why a webserver wouldn't require mTLS. But when is it normal for a server not to send the entire certificate chain? And as I mentioned in my post, I can observe the entire chain when I use openssl or even when I turn on Java SSL handshake debugging.

It's normal when the server doesn't have the entire certificate chain. We don't actually have your checkServerTrusted code to see if there's a problem there. Perhaps you can edit your question to make it a [mre] so we can run the code ourselves.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I went back to check my sanity and made sure that I was getting the entire chain and lo and behold, you are 100% right. I'm only receiving the main server certificate and none of the signers, and the client aliases aren't even present... Let me ask this question: How are the browsers able to show the entire certificate chain if they aren't being sent during the SSL handshake sequence?

That was a complication I hoped to avoid, but there is a way in some cases using an extension in a certificate to find the certificate that signed it. This extension is called the Authority Key Identifier, and this question talks about it.

You can also give the following code snippet a try: sslcontext-kickstart - extract server certificates I created a library in the past which can resolve the full chain automatically

user: it is (and has been) always permitted for a TLS server to not send the root cert because the client must ignore it and use only a root in its truststore, making the sent copy a waste of bandwidth that may delay connection startup. See RFC 8446 page 65, RFC 5246 p48, RFC 4346 p41, RFC 2246 p39. Whether a specific server uses this permission or sends the unneeded and useless root varies according to server software and configuration. Browsers show you the chain validated which is modified from the chain received.  (@PresidentJ)

Neardupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612772/does-a-tls-client-needs-to-have-intermediate-ca-in-the-trust-store and compare https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64415/how-are-browsers-able-to-find-and-construct-an-alternate-trusted-chain-path and https://superuser.com/questions/1403149/show-the-entire-trust-of-chain-using-open-ssl (disclosure: mine)
